# Python Flask show multiple results in a list

Tags: python, html, cisco

I am messing around with a script in Flask I have this portion here

```
def get_interfaces_list2(device):
    output_interfaces = device.send_command('show interfaces switchport')
    current_dir = os.getcwd()
    template_file = open(current_dir + "/scripts/textfsm/show_interface_switchport.template", "r")
    template = TextFSM(template_file)
    parsed_interfaces = template.ParseText(output_interfaces)

    interface_list = []
    for interface_data in parsed_interfaces:
        resultDict = {}
        resultDict["interface"] = interface_data[0]
        resultDict["admin_mode"] = interface_data[5]
        resultDict["access_vlan"] = interface_data[6]
        resultDict["voice_vlan"] = interface_data[8]
        resultDict["trunking_vlans"] = interface_data[9]

        interface_list.append(resultDict)
        Return interface_list



I would like to add another command to add more info from the switch 

   output_interfaces1 = device.send_command('show interfaces description')
    current_dir = os.getcwd()
    template_file = open(current_dir + "/scripts/textfsm/show_interface_description.template", "r")
    template = TextFSM(template_file)
    parsed_interfaces1 = template.ParseText(output_interfaces1)

    interface_list1 = []
    for interface_data1 in parsed_interfaces1:
        resultDict["descrip"] = interface_data1

        interface_list.append(interface_list1)

        return interface_list
```

I would like to combine this into a single list and return that info in an HTML

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are currently saving information about an interface in a dictionary and storing that dict in a list. You then want to add more information about the interface. I think there are two approaches you can take here:

1. Run a single for loop on both parsed_interfaces and parsed_interfaces1 and store all of the info in one shot.
2. Store the info from your first loop in another dictionary instead of a list where the key is the interface name. Then in the second loop use that key to access the nested dict and store the new info.

Comment: I think I like option 2, I will try to give that a shot.  Not sure how option 1 would look like.

Comment: for running it in a single loop am I looking at something like this   for interface, inter in zip(one, two):

    print (interface['interface'] + interface['admin_mode'] + inter['descrip'])

Comment: The single loop will not work "show int description" starts with the interfaces for vlans and includes Gi0/0, "show inter switchport" starts with my first physical interfaces Gi1/0/1.  So it looks like Option 2 would be the best option to go with.